# Multiple || in if statement

Tags: c++

The second loop always displays "invalid data" when I enter "cm", "m", "in", or "ft".
Am I doing something wrong with the OR statements?

```
#include "standard_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    string unit = "";
    double number = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    bool run = true;

    while (counter < 10){

        cout << "Enter unit: (cm, m, in, ft)"<<endl;
        cin >> unit;
        while (run)
        {
            if (unit != "cm" || unit != "m" || unit != "in" || unit != "ft")
            {
                cout << "invalid data" << endl;
                cin >> unit;
            }

                else
                    run = false;
        }
        cout << "Enter number: ";
        cin >> number;
        cout << number << unit << endl;

        run = true;
        ++counter;
    }

    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: take unit == "cm", and evaluate the condition manually. What does it give, and why?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate but I cannot locate one. Related [meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273262/canonical-language-agnostic-question-for-ifvar-x-var-y)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unit != "cm" || unit != "m" ...` will **always** evaluate to `true`. If `unit` is equal to "cm", it isn't equal to "m". You want to use AND (`&&`) instead of OR (`||`).

```
if (unit != "cm" && unit != "m" && unit != "in" && unit != "ft")
```

Answer (score 1):

`or` is the wrong operation here; it flags the input as invalid if *any* of those tests fail; in other words, the input would have to be all of `cm`, `m`, `in` and `ft` at the same time, which is impossible.

You want `and`, so that it only is invalid if *all* of those tests fail. Alternatively, it might be less confusing if you change the sense of the tests and check for a positive "is it valid?" rather than a double negative "is it not invalid?":

```
if (unit == "cm" || unit == "m" || unit == "in" || unit == "ft") {
    run = false;
} else {
    // invalid
}
```

Answer (score -2):

|| means "or".

Whatever you enter, it will be either different from "cm", or it will be different from "m", or different from "in", so whatever you type in is recognised as illegal.

Have a look at && (and).